# ERROR - 'Credentials' object has no attribute 'signer_email'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer, google-iam

I have a gRPC service deployed on Google Cloud Run which I want to call from Composer.

I have assigned the `roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator` role to the service account which my composer worker nodes are running under, and I'm not mounting any custom service key files or setting the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable.

Using the [`JWT_GOOGLE` authentication option](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/grpc/hooks/grpc.py#L100)  in the airflow gRPC hook I get the following error:

```bash
[2022-05-31 14:20:16,082] {grpc.py:90} INFO - Calling gRPC service
[2022-05-31 14:20:16,097] {taskinstance.py:1152} ERROR - 'Credentials' object has no attribute 'signer_email'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 985, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/providers/grpc/operators/grpc.py", line 95, in execute
    for response in responses:
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/providers/grpc/hooks/grpc.py", line 136, in run
    with self.get_conn() as channel:
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/providers/grpc/hooks/grpc.py", line 104, in get_conn
    jwt_creds = google_auth_jwt.OnDemandCredentials.from_signing_credentials(credentials)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/auth/jwt.py", line 695, in from_signing_credentials
    kwargs.setdefault("issuer", credentials.signer_email)
AttributeError: 'Credentials' object has no attribute 'signer_email'
[2022-05-31 14:20:16,100] {taskinstance.py:1196} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=example_dag, task_id=example_task, execution_date=20220531T135709, start_date=20220531T142015, end_date=20220531T142016
[2022-05-31 14:20:23,826] {local_task_job.py:102} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

Does anyone have any idea how/why my credentials aren't including the field I need?

Comment: You can  attach the service account with Cloud Run and [authenticate](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#manually) it manually. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I'm not sure that approach is relevant - we're running in GCP Composer, so the airflow worker has access to a service account which theoretically has the correct permissions here

Comment: It seems to be a problem with authentication. If you are trying to authenticate to the Cloud Composer API in IAP using a Service account, you need to obtain an OIDC token for authentication for which steps are given in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#authenticating_from_a_service_account) Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Please take a look at the link I included in the question - that's how Airflow's gRPC hook tries to get an account and I expect their code to work for the service account I'm using - I don't expect to have to do any additional authentication beyond this as that's what the airflow connection and hook are for

Comment: Hi TCB,  it appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new [GCP support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to this after discussing with Google Cloud - essentially, it looks like the `JWT_GOOGLE` authentication method isn't set up for GCE service accounts so I went down the `CUSTOM` authentication route instead:

```py
import google.auth.transport.grpc
import google.auth.transport.requests
import google.oauth2.credentials
import google.oauth2.id_token
from airflow.providers.grpc.operators.grpc import GrpcOperator

def connection_func(conn):
    """Custom connection function for gRPC authentication.

    Args:
        conn: Airflow Connection object

    Returns:
        An instantiated gRPC channel for making calls to our remote service.
    """

    request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()

    if not str(conn.host).startswith("https://"):
        audience = f"https://{conn.host}"
    else:
        audience = conn.host

    token = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(request, audience)
    creds = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(token)
    base_url = conn.host
    if conn.port:
        base_url = f"{base_url}:{conn.port}"
    channel = google.auth.transport.grpc.secure_authorized_channel(
        creds, None, base_url
    )
    return channel


return GrpcOperator(
        ...
        custom_connection_func=connection_func,
    )
```

This uses the approach seen [here](https://github.com/salrashid123/google_id_token/blob/master/python/main.py#L44) to fetch an ID token for a given audience, then create a set of credentials from there and finally instantiate the gRPC secure channel for use in the operator.